# Accessing specific list value using an index in Freemarker (NetSuite Advanced PDF)

Tags: java, freemarker, netsuite

I have a Freemarker list in NetSuite. It contains several line items of a purchase order, and I would like to ***access a specific value using an index***.

I have tried to print the desired value in the code below in the 2nd cell of the 2nd row (for debugging purposes only).

When I try to process the code, I don't get any specific error. NetSuite simply informs me that I cannot save the template, so I am not sure how to proceed.

```
<#if record.item?has_content>
    <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th>
        <th colspan="12">${item.item@label}</th>
        <th colspan="3">${item.options@label}</th>
        <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate@label}</th>
        <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </#if><tr class="${LineFormat(item.item, item_index)}">
        <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
        <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}}      ${item[item_index].rate}</td>
        <td colspan="3">${item.options}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.item?upper_case?contains("TAX")><#else>${item.rate}</#if></td>
        <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
        </tr>
        </#list><!-- end items --></table>
    </#if>
```

Comment: if "item" represents each line item, I am not sure what you are trying to do with ${item[item_index].rate}

Wouldn't ${item.rate} be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There's a stray `</#if>` at the very end.

BTW in such cases (the error message is eaten by something) you can check template syntax on http://try.freemarker.org/. (If you get some evaluation error, then you know that syntax was right, otherwise it doesn't get to that point.)

Comment: Sorry about that, there was a missing if statement at the very top that I forgot to paste in here. Added it now.

Comment: Now it's syntactically correct. Why do you think the problem is related to access by index? Does it save the template if you remove the  `${item[item_index].rate}`? That part is syntactically valid, though semantically it's strange (`item` is already the `item_index`-th item). You also has an extra `}` before that, though that's valid, even if surely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

LineFormat is likely the problem. This seems to be a custom function which is not displayed in your code.  Try removing the LineFormat function and printing item_index independently.